# Why is appending an int to a std::string undefined behavior with no compiler warning in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, append, undefined-behavior

In my code I use [logging statements](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog) in order to better see what's going on. Sometimes I write code like the following:

```
int i = 1337;
// More stuff...
logger->info("i has the following value: " + i);
```

When compiled and executed in debug mode this does not print out `i` as expected (this is how it would work in Java/C# for example), it rather prints something garbled. In release mode however this might as well crash the entire application. What does the `C++` standard say about appending ints to a `std::string` like I'm doing here?

Why does the compiler not warn me at all when I compile code invoking obvious undefined behavior like this? Am I missing something? I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (MSVC). The correct way to do the logging statement would be converting the int to a `std::string` explicitly:

```
logger->info("i has the following value: " + std::to_string(i));
```

However this bug easily slips through during development. My warning level is set to `Level4 (/W4)`.

Comment: `"i has the following value: "` is a c-string from the `c` language. You can't use `+` with it. Or more exact the `+` does not append.

Comment: The shown code does not append int to any `std::string`. That not what `" .... "+ #` does. `" ...."` is not a `std::string`, so that's the first thing. C++ is not C# or Java, and works in fundamentally different ways. Assuming otherwise always ends in tears.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that in

```
logger->info("i has the following value: " + i);
```

you are not working with `std::string`. You are adding an `int` to a string literal, ie a `const char[]` array. The `const char[]` decays into a `const char*` pointer in certain contexts. In this case, the `int` advances that pointer forward by 1337 characters, which is way beyond the end of the string literal, and therefore undefined behavior.

You should get a better compiler that warns you about this, ie:

```
foo.cc:7:42: warning: offset ‘1337’ outside bounds of constant string [-Warray-bounds]
    7 |     foo("i has the following value: " + i);
      |                                          ^
```

---

You can use a `std::string` literal like this:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std::literals;

void foo(std::string);

void bla() {
    int i = 1337;
    foo("i has the following value: "s + i);
}
```

and then you get a "nicer" error that "std::string + int" isn't a thing in C++:

```
foo.cc:8:40: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ and ‘int’)
    8 |     foo("i has the following value: "s + i);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~
      |         |                                |
      |         std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> int
...
going on for 147 lines
```

After this, it should be obvious that what you want is this instead:

```
logger->info("i has the following value: "s + std::to_string(i));
```

Using `std::string` literals avoids mistakes like this, because it turns warnings (which your compiler doesn't even give) into hard errors, forcing you to write correct code. So I recommend using the `s` suffix for all strings.

Comment: Great answer. `You should get a better compiler`: Haha, this is the latest MSVC compiler and I basically need to use the Windows development tools since my software is Windows only. It's good that at least `gcc` has this type of warning. Hopefully MSVC will have it soon as well since this can be frustrating.

Comment: MSVC I think has a warning for this in its [static code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6386?view=msvc-170). Seems like it would be nice to have this enabled more automatically.

Comment: You can use clang and gcc on windows without a lot of difficulty. Even if you prefer to use msvc to create your final product it’s useful to run your code through a second compiler for a different opinion.

Comment: `You should get a better compiler` That's not going to help a great deal.  The compiler will only [be able to] generate that warning when it _knows_ (at compile time, natch) that the index is out of bounds, and, more often than not, it won't know.  And in any case, even if the index is within bounds, you won't get a warning but the code will still not be doing what you intended.

Comment: @PaulSanders That was a dig at his complaint the compiler wouldn't warn him: *Why does the compiler not warn me...*

Comment: In that case, I think you missed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That was already stated in the question. The point of the `s` suffix is to protect against cases where you forget to convert something to `std::string` before adding to it (or before passing it to a function).

Answer (score 5):

This line is correct,

```
logger->info("i has the following value: " + i);
```

in the expression

```
"i has the following value: " + i
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic.

For example if you will write

```
logger->info("i has the following value: " + 6);
```

then this line has the same effect if to write

```
logger->info("the following value: ");
```

That is this line

```
logger->info("i has the following value: " + i);
```

is equivalent to the line

```
logger->info( &"i has the following value: "[i]);
```

> What does the C++ standard say about appending ints to a std::string
> like I'm doing here

In the expression there is no object of the type `std::string`. There is used a string literal that has just an ordinary array type that is an operand of an expression with the pointer arithmetic. In the expression the string literal is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `const char *`.